# How to knit directly to R object?

Tags: r, pipe, latex, knitr

I'd like to store a `knit()`ted document directly in R as an R object, as a *character vector*.

I know I can do this by `knit()`ing to a `tempfile()` and then import the result, like so:

```
library(knitr)
library(readr)
ex_file <- tempfile(fileext = ".tex")
knitr::knit(text = "foo", output = ex_file)
knitted_obj <- readr::read_file(ex_file)
knitted_obj
```

returns

```
# [1] "foo\n"
```

as intended.

Is there a way to do this *without* using a `tempfile()` and by directly "piping" the result to a vector?

---

*Why* on earth would I want this, you ask?

- `*.tex` string will be programmatically saved to disc, and rendered to PDF later. Reading rendered `*.tex` from disc in downstream functions would make code more complicated.
- Caching is just a whole lot easier, and *moving* this cache to a different machine.
- I am just really scared of side effects in general and file system shenanigans across machines/OSes in particular. I want to isolate those to as few (`print()`, `save()`, `plot()`) functions as possible.

Does that make me a bad (or just OCD) R developer?

Comment: this is related to, though not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45322657/how-can-i-capture-cli-tool-file-output-to-r-object-or-stdout) where I'd like to capture the output of a CLI tool (such as the downstream `texi2pdf`) directly in R, without touching the file system.
Knitr is native R so it's a different issue, I am guessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as straightforward as a single line like this:

```
knitted_obj = knitr::knit(text = "foo")
```

You may want to read the help page `?knitr::knit` again to know what it returns.

Comment: yikes. Thanks so much and sorry about the unnecessary question; did *not* read the second sentence of the return value doc.

Comment: I can understand why you didn't notice it. The vast majority of knitr's use cases are knitting files instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `con <- textConnection("varname", "w")` to create a connection that writes its output to variable `varname`, and use `output=con` in the call to `knit()`.  For example:

```
library(knitr)
con <- textConnection("knitted_obj", "w")
knit(text="foo", output = con)
close(con)
knitted_obj
```

returns the same as your tempfile approach, except for the newline.  Multiple lines will show up as different elements of `knitted_obj`.  I haven't timed it, but text connections have a reputation for being slow, so this isn't necessarily as fast as writing to the file system.