# How can I capture CLI tool file output to R object or stdout?

Tags: r, pipe, latex, command-line-interface, system

I'm calling a bunch of command-line interface (CLI) tools (such as [`texi2pdf`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/texi2pdf/) or [`pdf2svg`](http://www.cityinthesky.co.uk/opensource/pdf2svg/) from an R script, and I'd like to capture the output *file* of these tools *directly* as an R object, **without touching the file system**.

This is the *opposite* concern of the more frequent "how-do-I-redirect-stdout-to-file"-question. (Perhaps that implies that I'm "using it wrong").

**Example**:

Say, I have a simple latex `reprex.tex` file that I'd like to compile:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Foo.


\end{document}
```

In R, I can use the `tools::texi2pdf()` wrapper, or I can send the command myself to compile this to a pdf.

On the shell, simply:

```
texi2pdf reprex.tex
```

Equivalently, called from R:

```
reprex_as_pdf <- system2(command = "texi2pdf", args = c(reprex.tex), stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE)
```

Conveniently, `system2()` allows me to capture stdout/stderr as a character vector via `stdout = TRUE`, which gets me half of the way.

However, I can't seem to find anything in the [texi2pdf manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/texi2pdf/) that would allow me to redirect the (binary!) output to `stdout` (and that way, to `system2()`).

**How can I capture the output of `texi2pdf` *directly* in R as a (raw) vector?**

(Bonus: how can I also pass the *input* to `texi2pdf` as an R character vector, rather than as a file?)

---

**Work-Around**

I can of course work via a `tempfile()`, but that *would* touch the filesystem, and just seems inelegant / cumbersome.

```
library(readr)
system2(command = "texi2pdf",
        args = c("reprex.tex"),
        stdout = TRUE,
        stderr = TRUE)
reprex_as_pdf <- read_file_raw("reprex.pdf")
```

---

**Why** would anyone want to do this, you ask?

I'm generally scared of side-effects and cross-machine/OS file system shenanigans, and want to isolate the side effects to very few functions.
Also, the pdf will actually be programmatically exported, converted in all sorts of different functions.
Lastly, I need a *lot* of these pdfs, and I want them easily compiled and cached before deploying to a server which *may not have `texi2dvi`*.

Please stop me if I am just absolutely "using it wrong".

Comment: related to, though not a duplicate to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45321041/how-to-knit-directly-to-r-object) where I want to capture the output of `knitr::knit()` directly without touching the file system. `knit()` is native R though, so it's a different issue.

Comment: In python you have the possibility to attach string buffers to stdout of a process: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html. I don't know about R.

Also note, that you will usually not hit the disk, when writing to `/tmp` on Linux (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmpfs#cite_note-4). The content stays entirely in RAM. Hence performance can be quite good, although I agree it's cumbersome.

Comment: I guess I *will* have to learn Python at some point 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply: in the general case **you can’t**. But sometimes these tools allow you to specify an output file, in which case you can (on some systems, but note that this is *not portable*) specify `/dev/stdout` as the output file.

According to the `texi2pdf` manpage, the following should therefore work:

```
reprex_as_pdf <- system2(
    command = "texi2pdf",
    args = c("reprex.tex", "-o", "/dev/stdout"),
    stdout = TRUE, stderr = TRUE
)
```

However, this doesn’t prevent the tool from touching the file system in other ways (creating temporary files etc). There’s no way to prevent this, nor would it be desirable: these effects should be transparent to the user. The exception is the generation of multiple output files (e.g. log files), which TeX related tools unfortunately do prolifically.

To answer your bonus question: this is once again not possible in a platform independent way but on POSIX systems you can create a [named pipe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/mkfifo.1.html). However, for all intents and purposes from an R perspective this behaves like an ordinary file, and it’s managed by the file system.

Comment: Oh, I forgot: for input files you might, analogously, be able to use `/dev/stdin`. However, this could break in weird ways if the tool tries reading commands from stdin, in addition to reading an input file.